# Mouse event disturb by other activities on the screen - Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, mouseevent

Context : I'm using some mouse events in excel-vba to interact with another software. My mouse is moving and clicking at different places and everything is working well. Meanwhile, the goal of these instructions is to ask my other software to open a pdf file. I am working on 2 screens; my software is on one screen and my pdf are opening on the other one.

Issue : When the pdf file opened, it disturbs the activity of my mouse on my first screen. Consequently, it's not responsive when my mouse continue to click.

Is there a way to keep my first screen active whatever is happening on the other one?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: What's the code? Perhaps after the line where the user opens the PDF, you use `AppActivate` to call the Excel and other Software back to the forefront? Or even ask the user to select them again with the mouse, then have an "OK" message box to click?

Comment: your issue: when the pdf file is opened, it takes the focus away from the original program  ... web search "how to retain focus upon starting another program"